# Magento 2: upgrade module with EAV attributes

Tags: magento-2.1, eav, upgrade-script

I am working on a custom module with EAV attributes / models.
I have added some attribute in my setup script and the module is installed and working.
Now as the requirement changed, I need to add a new attribute in my script.
How can i write and upgrade script for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modify your setup file and add Upgrade Script.
Don't forget to change the module version
Step by Step :

1. Add new attribute to Setup file (in my case Setup/ContactSetup.php)
2. Add Upgrade Script (in my case Setup/UpgradeData.php)
3. Change version number (etc/module.xml)
4. Upgrade Module `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
5. Clear Cache `php bin/magento cache:clean`

AND DONE!!